# how to enable the filter of the video lens?

Tags: video

I did upgrade from 11.10 to 12.04 but I'm facing problem that the filter of the video lens is not enabled. Is there any help to enable this filter so I can search videos even on the network ? 
thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Please open a terminal and type

```
sudo apt-get install --reinstall unity-lens-video
```

This should reinstall the video lens just in case something went wrong during the update.
Please restart your computer and tell us if it worked.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply Daniel. unfortunately, still it doesn't work.

Comment: please type in a terminal " unity --version " (without the quotations) and post the output and please also verify, that the following files exist: /usr/share/unity/lenses/video/video.lens, /usr/share/unity/lenses/video/video-remote.scope, /usr/lib/unity-lens-video/unity-lens-video, /usr/lib/unity-scope-video-remote/unity-scope-video-remote

Comment: "unity 5.12.0"
and all these files are exist.

Comment: and you have restarted your machine right? Sorry if I sound stupid but I just want to avoid unnecessary work ;) And try this command from terminal: " sudo unity --reset "

Comment: I tried it but still doesn't work, also I have the "filter result" on the other lenses except the the video's lens. Thanks again Daniel